# Linking C/C++ STM32 project using arm-none-eabi-gcc, newlib and cmake

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, stm32

I'm having difficulty linking my STM32 project using CMake. The link command that is generated is:

```
/Users/jeremy/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -Og -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP  -std=c++11 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -specs=nano.specs -T/Users/jeremy/stm32l432kc_freertos_template/STM32L432KCUx_FLASH.ld -Wl,-Map=target.map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections 

< ... lots of .o files here ...>

-o stm32l432kc_freertos -lc -lm -lnosys
```

Unfortunately I get two sets of errors. The first is:

```
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol arch_paths_first; defaulting to 0000000008000190
```

which indicates that there is no entry symbol, but in the LD file the first line of code is: `ENTRY(Reset_Handler)`. The symbol `Reset_Handler` is defined in a linked file `startup_stm32l432xx.s`.

The second set of errors relate to the stdlib:

```
/Users/jeremy/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/libg_nano.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_kill_r':
signalr.c:(.text._kill_r+0xe): undefined reference to `_kill'
/Users/jeremy/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/libg_nano.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_getpid_r':
signalr.c:(.text._getpid_r+0x0): undefined reference to `_getpid'
```

Which are supposed to be solved by linking `-lnosys`, but the linker appears to be ignoring that.

Essentially, the linker appears to be ignoring some of the directives in the LD file and ignoring some of the flags I have passed. I realise it is probably something I am doing wrong, but I can't see what it is.

If I add `-specs=nosys.specs` the latter two errors go away, but this shouldn't be necessary? Can someone please help me understand what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CMake on OSX is adding the `-Wl,-search_paths_first` which is unsupported for the gcc arm toolchain. Fix is to add this to the CMakelists.txt file:

```
if ( APPLE )
    string ( REPLACE "-Wl,-search_paths_first" "" CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS} )
    string ( REPLACE "-Wl,-search_paths_first" "" CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} )
endif ()
```

Fix is taken from here: https://github.com/kiibohd/controller/blob/master/Lib/CMake/build.cmake

Still have no idea about the `-lnosys` being ignored though.